# Why does attempting to verbatimize this string fail?

Tags: c#, escaping, quotes, verbatim-string

I have this substring I want to strip out of a string:

```
<ArrayOfSiteQuery xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CStore.DomainModels.HHS">
```

Realizing it was full of funkiness, I thought verbatimizing it would solve all ills:

```
String messedUpJunk = @"<ArrayOfSiteQuery xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CStore.DomainModels.HHS">";
```

...but, to paraphrase the robot on Lost In Space, that does not compute (compile); I get, "*; expected*" on the first "http".

I can get it compilable by escaping the quotes:

```
String messedUpJunk = "<ArrayOfSiteQuery xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CStore.DomainModels.HHS\">";
```

...but what use is verbatim if it's not verbatimatic?

Comment: think about it, how could compiler possibly know where your string literals starts and ends if you don't escape `"`?

Comment: I would think verbatimizing should just tell the compiler "forget about trying to figure this out - just consider everything within the inner and outer quotes as a single string that you shouldn't mess with or try to parse."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A double quote is the only character you need to escape in verbatim strings. Escaping it is done differently, you need to double it (`""`) instead of using the backslash:

```
String messedUpJunk = @"<ArrayOfSiteQuery xmlns:i=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" 
xmlns=""http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CStore.DomainModels.HHS"">";
```

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx):

> Use double quotation marks to embed a quotation mark inside a verbatim string

Answer (score 3):

It is the double quote which requires escaping *(using double double quotes)*, for rest of the characters you don't need to escape, for example back slash `\`.

See: [2.4.4.5 String literals - C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28VS.71%29.aspx)

> A verbatim string literal consists of an @ character followed by a
>   double-quote character, zero or more characters, and a closing
>   double-quote character. A simple example is @"hello". In a verbatim
>   string literal, the characters between the delimiters are interpreted
>   verbatim, **the only exception being a quote-escape-sequence.** In
>   particular, simple escape sequences and hexadecimal and Unicode escape
>   sequences are not processed in verbatim string literals. A verbatim
>   string literal may span multiple lines.

The reason you need to escape double quote is because it represents start and end of string, whether verbatim or regular.

Comment: Ah good, my old fiend, I mean friend, is back; I was afraid he had croaked or something.